# Regular Expression for First name

Tags: regex

I've got a RegEx pattern fro user first and last name. They can only contain alphabetic characters, spaces (0 - any ), hyphens (0 - any), apostrophes **'** (0 - any ) and number of symbols 1 - 40. First and Last name can not start with '  or whitespace

Here is my pattern code.

```
^^[a-zA-Z]+[\-\'\s]?[a-zA-Z ]{1,40}$
```

But RegEx does now allow to use this sample  Endevald O'McKnight

Comment: `[a-zA-Z '-]{1,40}`?

Comment: @ctwheels, sorry forgot to add, first and last name can not start with '  or whitespace

Comment: Be careful about assuming too much. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: `[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z '-]{0,39}`? But as @AdrianWragg mentioned, you shouldn't assume this.

Comment: @ctwheels I'm using https://regex101.com. and unfortunately your RegEx does not match

Comment: @AlexandruIachimov I'm using regex101 and I guarantee it matches your sample.

Comment: @ctwheels Sorry, my bad. You right it works for my sample above, but does not work with 'Test'. String without any  ' (whitespace) -

Comment: Post a bunch of sample names, but it works for that example too

Comment: Sample names:
1.Test               Should match
2.Test'test                Should match
3.Test test                Should match
4.Test'test test         Should match
5.Test test'test         Should match
6.Test test test         Should match
7.Test'test test test  Should match
8.(whitespace)Test  Should not match

Comment: Try [`^(?=.{1,40}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-'\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ic0UPr/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it works !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{1,40}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-'\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ic0UPr/1).

**Details**

- `^` - a start of a string
- `(?=.{1,40}$)` - there must be 1 to 40 chars other than line break chars in the string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?:` - starto of a non-capturing group repeated 0 or more times matching sequences of

  - `[-'\s]` - a `-`, `'` or whitespace
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `)*` - end of the grouping
- `$` - end of string

Comment: what does the 1+ mean?

Comment: @shan "one or more"

Comment: in this context you are saying, you can type letters capital or lower case more than 1 time in repeating form?

Comment: @shan `[a-zA-Z]+` matches `aADffrddVG`, `a`, `A`, `aZ` like strings. Any ASCII letter in any order, 1 or more times.